# React-Native, Xamarin MessagingService like tool

Tags: xamarin, react-native, subscription

I used to develop app using `Xamarin`, it has a perfect ([This repo](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/xamarin.forms-toolkit)) and has the ability to `subscribe` and `sendMessage` from all over the app.

Now we're immigrated to `react-native` and we need such a tool (except `Redux`). Is there a simple tool like `Messaging Service` in `react-native`?

Comment: I have same issue

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Redux, you might want to look into [undux](https://github.com/bcherny/undux). It's a state manager that's also based on the flux principle, but easier to learn and implement than Redux.